# Deleting columns of a data.table inside a function

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following example:

```
irisDT <- as.data.table(iris)

mod <- function(dat) {
  dat[, index:=(1:nrow(dat))]
  setkey(dat, index)

  dat <- dat[2:10]

  dat[, index:=NULL]
  invisible()
}

mod(irisDT)
names(irisDT) # it contains index
```

To my surprise,  the index column still exists after calling the `mod()`
function.
This is not the case when I delete the line `dat <- dat[2:10]`.
I guess that, since rows cannot be deleted by reference yet, another
data.table is created.
However, I would like to delete the index column in the original
data.table.

Comment: Please don't start your title with "R: "; that is what the tags are for.

Comment: +1 bumped 100% in the same problem today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question.  `data.table` **is** copied-on-change, by `<-`, in the usual R way.

It isn't copied-on-change by `:=` or the `set*` functions (`setkey`,`setnames`,`setattr`) provided by the `data.table` package.

So it's not anything special about the `data.table` object itself that decides copies or not, and it's passed as an argument to functions in exactly the same way as `data.frame`. It's what you do on it inside the function that counts. The `<-` operator copies-on-change and that's no different when used on a `data.table`. The `:=` operator, on the other hand, assigns by reference.

As you say, there is no way (yet) to delete rows by reference, so until then you'll need to use standard R syntax to assign the copy back to the symbol in calling scope.

As it happens, there was a slide on this at last night's LondonR talk which is now on the [homepage](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) under the presentation section (see slide with title `copy()`).

Comment: Thanks! I'll use copy indeed.